# Negative Binomial Coefficients -nCk = (n+k-1)Ck

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I am unable to understand that why $\binom{-n}{k} = \binom{n+k-1}{k}.$ Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 2):

For $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we define
$$
\binom{\alpha}{k}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsb(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}.
$$
In particular, in your case
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-n}{k}
&=\frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)\dotsb(-n-k+1)}{k!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^kn(n+1)(n+2)\dotsb(n+k-1)}{k}\tag{0}\\
&={(-1)^k}\binom{n+k-1}{k}
\end{align}
$$
where in (0) we factored a minus one from each of the terms in the product in the numerator.